# Remote pagination and last_page: filter during, or after, database query?

Tags: tabulator

I would like to use Tabulator's remote pagination to load records from my database table, one page at a time. I expect that I should be able to use the page and size parameters sent by Tabulator to my remote back-end to determine which records to select from the database.
For example, with page=2 and size=10, I can use MySQL's LIMIT 10,20 to select the records to be shown on page 2 (if size is set to 10).

However, doing this precludes me from using the count of all records to determine the number of pages in the table.  Doing a count on the returned records will only yield 10 records, even if there are a total of 500 records (for example), so only one pagination button will be shown (instead of the expected 50 buttons).

So in order to do remote pagination "correctly" in Tabulator, it seems I must do a query to count all records from my database (with no limits), then do a count to determine the last_page, and then do something like PHP's array_slice to extract the nth page's worth of records to return as the dataset. Or I can do 2 database queries: count all records to determine # of pages, and then do a LIMIT [start],[end] query.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabulator needs to know the last page number in order to layout the pagination buttons in the table footer so that users can select the page they want to view from the list of pages.

You simply need to do a query to count the total number of records and divide it by the number of page size which is passed in the request. you can run a count query quite efficiently returning only the count and no data.

You can then run a standard query with a limit set on the records to retreive the records for that page.

If you want to optimize things further you could stick the count value in cache so that you dont need to generate it on each request.

Comment: Got it, thx, good point about caching the count.